# How to save user input image in ImageField of Django Model

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to save a user image in my database. Below is my input form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/savedata/">
{% csrf_token %}
<input id="file-upload" type="file"  accept="image/*" name='profileimg' />
<input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```

How could I save the selected image in the database using *form submit*

**My model class:**

```
class usertab(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_img')
```

I am able to save an image using *superuser* but I need to save this using submission form, how could I possibly do it?

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for submit file in django you should use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` property in your form and get it in your view with `myfile = request.FILES['myfile']`

```
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="file" name="myfile">
   <button type="submit">Upload</button>
 </form>
```

views:

```
def simple_upload(request):
   if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
      myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
      # statements
```

---

[Ref](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html)

Comment: sir it is work but if i am not select a file and submit form then it give me error `MultiValueDictKeyError myfile` how can i do this file field is required

Comment: check is there `myfile` key in request or not for example if you pass your file with `myfile` key you can check it like `if 'myfile' in request.POST:'

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag. It is required when dealing with uploaded files.